# Groovy merge YAML file wihout duplicates

Tags: groovy, yaml

I want to merge configuration file :

```
tool:
 jdk:
 - name: jdk8
   version: 8
 - name: jdk11
   version: 11
```

with file :

```
tool:
  jdk:
 - name: jdk11
   version: 11
 - name: jdk15
   version: 15
```

I expect as a result :

```
tool:
 jdk:
 - name: jdk8
   version: 8
 - name: jdk11
   version: 11
 - name: jdk15
   version: 15
```

Without duplicates. Am currently using the solution from @szymon-stepniak  :
https://e.printstacktrace.blog/how-to-merge-two-maps-in-groovy/#merge-maps-with-nested-maps

any idea on how I could avoid having duplicate ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: in your yaml `jdk` is an array and solution is for maps. to make array unique you have to write custom code.

Comment: @daggett I don't know groovy but the custom code should be as simple as transforming the list into a LinkedHashSet since `equals` on a map of strings works as expected and the order will be preserved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code:

```
import groovy.yaml.*

def dataA = '''\
tool:
  jdk:
    - name: jdk8
      version: 8
    - name: jdk11
      version: 11
'''

def dataB = '''\
tool:
  jdk:
    - name: jdk11
      version: 11
    - name: jdk15
      version: 15
'''

def parser = new YamlSlurper()

def a = parser.parseText(dataA)
def b = parser.parseText(dataB)

def c = [tool: [jdk: (a.tool.jdk + b.tool.jdk).unique()]]

println "a: $a"
println "b: $b"
println "c: $c"

def builder = new YamlBuilder() 
builder c

println(builder)
```

when run, results in:

```
─➤ groovy solution.groovy
a: [tool:[jdk:[[name:jdk8, version:8], [name:jdk11, version:11]]]]
b: [tool:[jdk:[[name:jdk11, version:11], [name:jdk15, version:15]]]]
c: [tool:[jdk:[[name:jdk8, version:8], [name:jdk11, version:11], [name:jdk15, version:15]]]]
---
tool:
  jdk:
  - name: "jdk8"
    version: 8
  - name: "jdk11"
    version: 11
  - name: "jdk15"
    version: 15
```

This solution is not very generic as we hard code the `x.tool.jdk` path. An alternative would have been to write some kind of recursive merge function which can do this in a more generic manner.

**Update after comments:**

For the question in the comment you can do something like this:

```
def a = [tool: [jdk: [installations:
          [[name: 'latest-11', 
            properties: [[installSource: [installers:[[zip:[subdir:'jdk-11.999', url:'https://artifactory/OpenJDK11U_11.0.3_7.tar.gz']]]]]]]]]]] 

def b = [tool: [jdk: [installations:
          [[name: 'latest-11',  properties: [[installSource:[installers:[[zip:[subdir:'jdk-11.37', url:'https://artifactory/OpenJDK11U_11.0.3_7.tar.gz']]]]]]], 
           [name: 'jdk-11.0.3', properties: [[installSource:[installers:[[zip:[subdir:'jdk-11.3', url:'https://artifactory/OpenJDK11U_11.0.3_7.tar.gz']]]]]]]]]]]

def uniqueInstallations = (a.tool.jdk.installations + b.tool.jdk.installations).toUnique { x, y -> x.name <=> y.name }
def c = [tool: [jdk: [installations: uniqueInstallations]]]

uniqueInstallations.each { 
  println it
}

println "=="
println c
```

which prints:

```
➤ groovy solution2.groovy
[name:latest-11, properties:[[installSource:[installers:[[zip:[subdir:jdk-11.999, url:https://artifactory/OpenJDK11U_11.0.3_7.tar.gz]]]]]]]
[name:jdk-11.0.3, properties:[[installSource:[installers:[[zip:[subdir:jdk-11.3, url:https://artifactory/OpenJDK11U_11.0.3_7.tar.gz]]]]]]]
==
[tool:[jdk:[installations:[[name:latest-11, properties:[[installSource:[installers:[[zip:[subdir:jdk-11.999, url:https://artifactory/OpenJDK11U_11.0.3_7.tar.gz]]]]]]], [name:jdk-11.0.3, properties:[[installSource:[installers:[[zip:[subdir:jdk-11.3, url:https://artifactory/OpenJDK11U_11.0.3_7.tar.gz]]]]]]]]]]]
```

Comment: Thanks, I will definetely try this

Comment: It works thanks a lot, I need now to make it work with Jenkins. The issue is that it requires groovy 3.0, right ?

Comment: Yeah seems the YamlBuilder class was added in groovy 3. You could always pull in a library like snake yaml instead if you are locked to a lower groovy version.

Comment: Thank you very much Matias, it works. I used 
`import org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml`
to load the Yaml files.
Cheers

Comment: If you feel that the answer solved your problem, feel free to mark it as accepted so that others do not invest work on writing up more solutions for your problem.

Comment: do you know a way to limit the uniqueness to the name and not the whole "object" ?
Like : 
`c = [tool: [jdk: [installations: (a + b).unique(name)]]]`
So the unique key is the name whatever the rest is.

Comment: you can do `c = [tool: [jdk: [installations: (a+b).toUnique { x, y -> x.name <=> y.name }]]]` where `toUnique` takes a two argument closure as argument and is expected to return zero when the two items are considered "same" and non-zero otherwise. References: [Iterable.toUnique()](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/lang/Iterable.html#toUnique(groovy.lang.Closure)), [groovy spaceship operator](https://groovy-lang.org/operators.html#_spaceship_operator).

Comment: I have those 2 configs I want to merge, but not 2 times with name "latest-11"

`A: [tool:[jdk:[installations:[[name:latest-11, properties:[[installSource:[installers:[[zip:[subdir:jdk-11.999, url:https://artifactory/OpenJDK11U_11.0.3_7.tar.gz]]]]]]]]]]]`

`B: [tool:[jdk:[installations:[[name:latest-11, properties:[[installSource:[installers:[[zip:[subdir:jdk-11.37, url:https://artifactory/OpenJDK11U_11.0.3_7.tar.gz]]]]]]], [name:jdk-11.0.3, properties:[[installSource:[installers:[[zip:[subdir:jdk-11.3, url:https://artifactory/OpenJDK11U_11.0.3_7.tar.gz]]]]]]]]]]]`

Comment: Answer updated with another solution based on the last comment.